# Duty-free shopping Paris Charles de Gaulle

Tags: customs-and-immigration, paris, shopping, cdg

I'm travelling to France from Australia but will be flying via Greece on the way home. We fly out from Paris CDG terminal 2D. I was hoping to do some shopping at 2E before leaving as it's not great in Athens. I will have a flight ticket to show that we leave the EU a few days later. **Will I be able to access terminal 2E for shopping?**

I should have checked before booking all of our flights, but everything is booked now.

Answer (score 8):

You won't be able to do DF shopping, for 2 reasons. One is that you won't be able to access 2E, since your flight is from 2D. These two terminals are segregated. And should you even be able to access 2E for some reason, your boarding pass to Athens would preclude you from being able to buy anything, since your destination is within the EU. (**UPDATE:** I read your question as you having 2 separate flights, CDG-Athens, and Athens-OZ, with a few days in between, which means you won't have in CDG your boarding pass to OZ).

Bottom line, do whatever shopping you can in Athens... :-)

Comment: Thanks - could i claim the tax free when leaving Paris still being that we are going back to Australia a few days later?

Comment: According to https://cdgfacile.com/boutique-dutyfree-aeroport-roissy-cdg what matters is your final destination, so the boarding pass for Athens­–[non-EU] should allow duty-free purchases. However, the first reason applies: you'll only be able to access the duty-free from the Schengen zone of terminal 2D, and I would guess the options are limited (possibly none, if terminal 2D doesn't have flights to Switzerland).

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' From what I understand OP does not connect directly to non-EU flight in Athens, they stay for a few days before taking another flight, so the duty free shop will likely not apply the actual duty free price with only an intra-EU boarding pass.

Comment: @Sharon not without your Athens-OZ boarding pass. You can do that, again, in Athens: I understand you're not just transferring in Athens but staying a few days, right?

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' Final destination in this case is, for all concerned, Athens. OP won't be able to buy any DF in CDG.

Answer (score 4):

I can’t swear it, but I don’t think this is possible.

Generally, they won’t let you enter a terminal which doesn’t match your departing flight.

Even if they did in some cases, here you want to access an area which is past passport control, when you are booked on a Schengen flight.

Also, CDG have a click and collect service which allows you to get some items delivered to your departure terminal, but they require you to be booked to a non-EU destination.

You are probably better off making your purchases in town and claiming a tax refund when you leave. You’ll also generally have more choice.

Comment: Thanks - I thought this may be the case... Should have done my research!

Comment: Do you think i can claim back the vat if I shop in Paris? We go to Greece for a few days then back to Australia

Comment: @Sharon Yes, many shops allow duty-free purchases, you must present your non-EU passport, fill out a form, and when you leave the EU (so in Athens, if as I understood it you will be staying a few days there before exiting the EU), present the goods and the form to the local customs tax refund desk, who will stamp it, and you will get the tax refunded. Exact details vary, and you don't get all of the tax back (the processor will keep a commission), but it's a very common procedure. Just make sure the shop you buy from does it (large stores certainly do).

Comment: thank you - I will be travelling with my British passport this time which is an old red one! I will bring my Australian permanent residency Visa and flight tickets with me - do you think this will work? Sorry for all the questions!

Comment: @Sharon As the UK is not longer in the EU, that works for the initial part (in the shop). The flight details will probably be needed in Athens for the second part (duty free check). Don't forget you need to do that before you check-in, and that it can take a while in some places.